# Google Charts interpolateNulls does not work

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have a simple Google line chart.

When there is a null value the chart does not display at all.

Please note in the options I am using interpolateNulls: true.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load("current",{packages:["corechart"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable    ([
                                                         ["Term","Overall Attainment","Overall Effort"  ]
                                                        ,["Autumn 1 2021",0.222,0.388],["Autumn 2 2021",0.444,0.166]
                                                        ,["Spring 1 2022",0.222,0.222],["Autumn 1 2022",0.75,0.562],["Spring 1 2023",NULL,NULL]
                                                    ]);

var options = {
    legend: "right",
    interpolateNulls: true,
    chartArea: {
         left:50
        ,top: 20
        ,width:"50%"
        ,height:"55%"
    },
    vAxis: {
         direction: -1
        ,title: "Grade"
        ,ticks: [0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4]
        ,titleTextStyle: {
             bold: true
            ,fontName: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'
            ,fontSize: 14
            ,italic: false
        }
    },
    hAxis: {
         slantedText: true
        ,title: "Term"
        ,titleTextStyle: {
             bold: true
            ,fontName: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'
            ,fontSize: 14
            ,italic: false
        }
        ,slantedTextAngle: 50
    },
    curveType: "function",
    pointSize: 5
};
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("div1"));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
<div id="div1" style="width:700; height:400;"></div>
```

All my efforts cannot get this to work.

Any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null` should be all lowercase...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load("current", {
  packages: ["corechart"]
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Term", "Overall Attainment", "Overall Effort"],
    ["Autumn 1 2021", 0.222, 0.388],
    ["Autumn 2 2021", 0.444, 0.166],
    ["Spring 1 2022", 0.222, 0.222],
    ["Autumn 1 2022", 0.75, 0.562],
    ["Spring 1 2023", null, null]
  ]);

  var options = {
    legend: "right",
    interpolateNulls: true,
    chartArea: {
      left: 50,
      top: 20,
      width: "50%",
      height: "55%"
    },
    vAxis: {
      direction: -1,
      title: "Grade",
      ticks: [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4],
      titleTextStyle: {
        bold: true,
        fontName: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
        fontSize: 14,
        italic: false
      }
    },
    hAxis: {
      slantedText: true,
      title: "Term",
      titleTextStyle: {
        bold: true,
        fontName: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
        fontSize: 14,
        italic: false
      },
      slantedTextAngle: 50
    },
    curveType: "function",
    pointSize: 5
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("div1"));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: Fantastic, OMG such a simple reason.  Works again.